# Should I just use `==` to compare to `(None, None)` tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, nonetype, comparison-operators

I have a function, which can return either a tuple of two ints or a tuple of `(None, None)`:

*(for the purposes of this question, let's assume that this return format is the only way to do this, and it cannot be changed)*

```
from typing import Tuple, Union

def foo(n: int) -> Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[None, None]]:
    if n < 0:
        return None, None
    return n, n
```

Then I want to write a `pytest` unittest to test this function. It's always said that one should compare to `None` with `is`, but this obviously doesn't work:

```
def test_foo():
    assert foo(1) == (1, 1)
    assert foo(-1) is (None, None)  # fails obviously!
```

Should I in this situation just use `==` to compare the result?

```
def test_foo():
    assert foo(1) == (1, 1)
    assert foo(-1) == (None, None)  # best way?
```

Comment: You don't compare with `None`, you compare with a tuple (that happens to contain `None`). So comparison with `==` is the way to go.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah, that was my assumption about this, but since I couldn't find any questions asking this, I wanted to a) make sure that my assumption was correct and b) make the answer available for others in the future also :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `==`, but indeed it's not "obvious" that using `is` would fail.

For example

```
def foo():
    return (1, 2)

print(foo() is foo())
```

**MAY** actually return `True` (it does in CPython, not sure about other implementations).

Tuples are NOT to be considered entities, but values. Identity on values shouldn't be used as it may match or not (like happens for example for strings or numbers).

If in the code above you use `[1, 2]` instead of `(1, 2)` then it's guaranteed that `is` will return `False` because lists are entities, not values, and identity can be used in predictable ways.

Comment: In Python, tuples are objects because everything is an object. but Python confuses the matter by not having a good term for "objects that are conventionally only compared by value".

Comment: @DavidJones: indeed... I changed the term to "entity" to avoid object

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion, using a list comprehension to check `is None` for all return values:

```
def test_foo():
    assert foo(1) == (1, 1)
    assert all(i is None for i in foo(-1))
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `assert all(i is None for i in foo(-1))` fyi! You don't need to make a list, just use a generator expression.